# FFmpeg : Some blend filter options are missing

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video

FFmpeg gets the following error when I use `interpolate` or `softdifference` options of blend filter :

> [blend @ 000001cc06193640] [Eval @ 0000000477dfe5e0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'interpolate'
> [blend @ 000001cc06193640] Unable to parse option value "interpolate"
> [blend @ 000001cc06193640] [Eval @ 0000000477dfe5f0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'interpolate'
> [blend @ 000001cc06193640] Unable to parse option value "interpolate"
> [blend @ 000001cc06193640] Error setting option all_mode to value interpolate.
> [Parsed_blend_1 @ 000001cc06193540] Error applying options to the filter.
> [AVFilterGraph @ 000001cc06231d00] Error initializing filter 'blend' with args 'all_mode=interpolate'
> Error initializing complex filters.
> Invalid argument

I'm using FFmpeg 4.4 [Gyan's build](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/), please tell me which version supports these blend options?

Comment: 5.0 or current git

Comment: @Gyan, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake, the options I asked about are in FFmpeg 5.0.

Thanks to Gyan.